# Effects of n95 respirator in-flight - from the point of view of ambient oxygen level

Tags: face-mask-respirator, oxygen, hypoxia

I have a generic question about the usage of n95/99 or higher filtration respirators in high-altitude flights. With current pandemic situation we see many government/airlines are enforcing the use of mask in-flight. Now, although the cabin is usually pressurized to 8000ft when cruising, ambient O2 concentration inside the cabin stays below normal [1,2].  As per the datasheet of 3m n95 respirator - "Do not use in atmosphere containing less than 19.5% oxygen."

Does the use of respirator in-flight, along with low ambient O2 level, pose possible dangers of hypoxia? Or any other serious illness?

Reference:

1. Aldrette JA, Aldrette LE. Oxygen concentrations in commercial aircraft flights. South Med J. 1983;76(1):12‐14.
2. Humphreys, S., Deyermond, R., Bali, I., Stevenson, M., & Fee, J. P. H. The effect of high altitude commercial air travel on oxygen saturation. Anaesthesia. 2005; 60(5), 458-460.

Comment: You need a link to prove that oxygen percentages drop in a pressurised cabin. This seems rather unlikely.

Comment: barometric pressure x 0.209 (atmospheric fraction of O2) = atmospheric Po2. At sea level, 760 x 0.209 = 159 mm Hg. While at 8000ft, 564 mm Hg x 0.209 = 118 mm Hg. With less driving pressure it is similar to lower O2 concentration. Anyhow I have added some references above.

Comment: Oxygen pressure drops but the percentage you said also drops.  What is it replaced by?

Comment: The relative mix of gasses in air does not change with altitude. Only the pressure changes, so the N95 datasheet's warning doesn't appear to be relevant.

Comment: Yeah, they feed in stored air to help pressurize the compartments.